# Why does WorkManager tasks hang sometimes in my OneTimeWorkRequest?

Tags: android, android-sqlite, android-workmanager

I'm aware that that

> All background work is given a maximum of ten minutes to finish its execution

and that it may take it's time depending on certain things

My code belows creates 8 OneTimeWorkRequests then puts them what im hoping is a chain then is enqueued;

```
 workManager.beginWith(deleteCurrent)
                                    .then(deleteCurrentImages)
                                    .then(insertData)
                                    .then(insertImage)
                                    .then(insertAutoNames)
                                    .then(insertAutoCondition)
                                    .then(checkComplete)
                                    .enqueue();
```

The last request is to finish the current activity (if it reaches this request, it's assumed all tasks ran successfully) see below.

```
public class CheckComplete extends Worker {
    @NonNull
    @Override
    public Result doWork() {
        MyApplication myApplication = null;
        boolean run = true;
        Context context = getActivity();
        myApplication = (MyApplication) context.getApplicationContext();
        SQLiteConnection mybdc = myApplication.getData();


        String jobNo = getInputData().getString("jobNo", "");
        String section = getInputData().getString("section", "");
        int viewSize =  getInputData().getInt("viewSize", 0);
        int result = checkLastEntry(jobNo, section,viewSize, mybdc);

        if (1 == result) {
            getActivity().finish();
            return Result.SUCCESS;
        } else {
            Message.message(context, "Error occurred, please try and save again");
            return Result.FAILURE;
        }
    }

    public int checkLastEntry(String jobNo, String section, int viewSize, SQLiteConnection mydbc) {
        ArrayList<String> values = new ArrayList<>();



        try {
            SQLiteStatement mystatement = null;

                mystatement = mydbc.prepareStatement("SELECT value FROM documentTable WHERE jobNo = '" + jobNo + "' AND section = '" + section + "'");
                while (mystatement.step()) {
                    values.add(mystatement.getColumnTextNativeString(0));
                }

            } catch (SQLException ex) {

                try {
                    File path = new File("/sdcard/exports/logs");
                    SimpleDateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MM-yyyy HH:mm:ss");
                    String currentDateTime = dateFormat.format(new Date()) + " ";
                    File myFile = new File(path, "DBCrashes.txt");
                    FileOutputStream fOut = new FileOutputStream(myFile, true);
                    OutputStreamWriter myOutWriter = new OutputStreamWriter(fOut);
                    myOutWriter.append("\n" +
                            "\r");
                    myOutWriter.append(currentDateTime + " Error reading values: " + ex);
                    myOutWriter.close();
                    fOut.close();
                    return 0;
                } catch (java.io.IOException e) {

                    return 0;


                }
            }
            if(values.size()==viewSize) {
                return 1;
            }else{
                return 0;
            }

            }


    }
```

There is a class for each OneTimeWorkRequests (besides insertAutoNames/Condition)
I put a break point on each return line in doWork().

For some reason when I run it sometimes it just hangs and would not reach the next tasks return line what could be causing this?

Edit: The workers begin when a "save" button is pressed, if it hangs this should allow the user to push save again, this will run the line below then run the commands above, however it doesn't seem to cancel the threads at work.

```
workManager.cancelAllWork();
```

Should I even be using WorkManager to query the database?

Previously I had it on a main thread but had some problems.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot assume that there will be an `Activity` running when your Worker is being run. This is because `JobScheduler` may run your `Worker` alone in the background. You should be using `getWorkInfoById()` instead.

Comment: for cancelling jobs incase they hang?